# Redmine suddenly stopped working. How to troubleshoot?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-10.04, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, redmine

I was a happy user of redmine for like 6 months. My plan was to set it up and never update anything in order not to deal with dependencies and stuff.

I'm using Ubuntu server 10.04 (Apache/Passenger) with disabled all kinds of updates.

This morning I started getting Internal Error in browser.

Log file says something like:

```
Processing WelcomeController#index (for 192.168.1.23 at 2012-03-05 10:44:12) [GET]
  Parameters: {"action"=>"index", "controller"=>"welcome"}

NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
    /app/models/setting.rb:100:in `value='
    /vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2589:in `send'
    /vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2589:in `attributes='
    /vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2585:in `each'
    /vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2585:in `attributes='
    /vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb:2285:in `initialize' 
...
```

I'm new to Ruby/Rails, and it is about the last thing I wanted to learn about at the moment. How do I get a clue what's wrong so I can try and fix it?

Comment: Btw, I've also tried rebooting the machine, touching restart.txt - no luck.

Comment: Same problem here. Probably it happened after some ruby upgrades from official ubuntu repo. In my /var/log/apt/history.log i've entries like this >ruby1.8 (1.8.7.249-2, 1.8.7.249-2ubuntu0.1), libruby1.8 (1.8.7.249-2, 1.8.7.249-2ubuntu0.1), libreadline-ruby1.8 (1.8.7.249-2, 1.8.7.249-2ubuntu0.1) It could be related to the problem I think

Comment: I'll check the log. I'm pretty sure I have all updates turned off, as I really don't want to care about the future dependencies. I'm just happy the way things worked before.

Comment: Confirmed! I have these upgrades in both /var/log/apt/history.log and /var/log/dpkg.log (actually older logs).

Answer (score 1):

Hash map security fix in ubuntu ruby package caused hash maps have different order of keys, randomly. But in redmine 0.9.3, which is ubuntu redmine package version, settings.rb has value= atribute accessor, which is dependent on correct attribute hash order (:name first, :value second).

Here is description of the bug and possible fix:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/redmine/+bug/949011
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/revisions/8909/diff/trunk/app/models/setting.rb

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I was not the only one.

Luckily - restarting (or reloading) Apache ONLY (as opposed to restarting the machine) does help. Some had to restart Apache twice. Apache error log doesn't help either.

http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/29317
http://www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/29209